# How to highlight Text line by line in React Native

Tags: react-native, text, highlight

I want to do text highlight in my React Native app. I am using React Native's Text component to display the text and I can give it a backgroundColor, but what I what is real highlight like you have it in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [react-native-highlight-words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) library for this.

Here is an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 300}}>
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'greenyellow'}}
          searchWords={["Swine Flu is an infection caused by"]}
          textToHighlight="Swine Flu is an infection caused by..."
        />
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}}
          searchWords={["swine flu"]}
          textToHighlight="The risk of swine flu..."
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```